# how do i Filter Only from date [without time] in MS Access Query

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

How doi find something only date, the query need time too

```
 (((TABLE.[UpdatedDate])=#31/07/2018#))
```

== No result

```
  (((TABLE.[UpdatedDate])=#31/07/2018 13:20:43#))
```

== Then result done.

i need to search from date only.

Comment: Have you tried  `>= 31/07/2018 00:00:00`? Like, take the earliest time possible and show everything bigger than that. And maybe also a filter `<= 31/07/2018 23:59:99`

Comment: thank you it is hard with my parameters....

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? You only can use one parameter as a filter or you cant use `>=`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
((( CDate(Format(TABLE.[UpdatedDate], "yyyy-mm-dd")) )=#31/07/2018#))
```

Comment: Wow, Arslan it is the answer. thank you , thank soooo much

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to format the first DateTime variable to just date only. Something like Birthday.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") for the first check. Perhaps store it in another variable and use that for the first check.

Than use the DateTime data you have to do the second check.

Comment: Thank you. it is not working for me because i need the time some water. and some times i need only date, i am seeking a solution without changing database. Any idea please?

Comment: But if you want both date and time, than just sending in a DateTime parameter will do both of it.

Comment: this is my insert
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UpdatedDate", DateTime.Now.ToString());